# How to order an array of strings representing software versions?

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an unordered array like this

```
["1.0",
 "1.10",
 "1.2",
 "1.6",
 "1.11.1",
 "1.3.1",
 "1.8",
 "1.11.2",
 "1.7.1",
 "1.1.3",
 "1.7",
 "1.6.1",
 "1.6.2",
 "1.9",
 "1.4.1",
 "1.4.1.1",
 "1.4",
 "1.6.3",
 "1.4.1.2",
 "1.5",
 "1.3",
 "1.11",
 "1.1.2"]
```

And need to get the ordered version (to get the last version). I thought about using a `semver` library to compare them, but these not follow `semver` convention so I don't know what it the proper way to achieve what I want.

UPDATE

versions strings are not Ruby specific, I could receive as input versions from all languages that one can find on Github

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One might use [`Gem::Version`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Version.html)

```
versions.sort_by(&Gem::Version.method(:new))
#⇒ ["1.0", "1.1.2", "1.1.3", "1.2", "1.3", "1.3.1",
#   "1.4", "1.4.1", "1.4.1.1", "1.4.1.2", "1.5",
#   "1.6", "1.6.1", "1.6.2", "1.6.3", "1.7", "1.7.1",
#   "1.8", "1.9", "1.10", "1.11", "1.11.1", "1.11.2"]
```

Comment: Seems good.. but I need to specify that I am not talking only of ruby versions... could be also PHP and other languages.. do you think something would change?

Comment: While the version follows the pattern `MAJOR.MINOR.BUILD.SUFFIX` convention, everything would be fine. Do not expect this to sort `"Version5"` or like insane versions properly though.

Comment: hope that not OSS repo adopt something like this :D

Comment: Everybody professional enough had [SemVer](http://semver.org/) adopted years ago.

Comment: one last question, never seen the construct `&something`, where I can read about it?

Comment: E.g. here: http://www.skorks.com/2013/04/ruby-ampersand-parameter-demystified/ :: basically it’s a shorthand to `versions.sort_by { |v|
 Gem::Version.new(v) }`.

Answer (score 2):

An array like yours, i.e. strings consisting of numbers separated by dots, can be sorted via:

```
a.sort_by { |s| s.split('.').map(&:to_i) }
#=> [
# "1.0",
# "1.1.2",
# "1.1.3",
# "1.2",
# "1.3",
# "1.3.1",
# "1.4",
# "1.4.1",
# "1.4.1.1",
# "1.4.1.2",
# "1.5",
# "1.6",
# "1.6.1",
# "1.6.2",
# "1.6.3",
# "1.7",
# "1.7.1",
# "1.8",
# "1.9",
# "1.10",
# "1.11",
# "1.11.1",
# "1.11.2"
# ]
```

`split('.')` separates the string:

```
'1.4.1.1'.split('.')
#=> ["1", "4", "1", "1"]
```

`map(&:to_i)` is a shortcut for `map { |e| e.to_i }`, it converts each element to an integer:

```
["1", "4", "1", "1"].map(&:to_i)
#=> [1, 4, 1, 1]
```

[`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) then uses these arrays to sort the corresponding strings.

Comment: `to_i` will fail on `.rc-1` suffixes sorting, and the latter is quite common in versions.

Comment: @mudasobwa it will only work for numeric versions like in the OP's example. That's why I said _"An array like yours, i.e. strings consisting of numbers separated by dots"_

Comment: Yes, I see, I just dropped this comment to make it crystal clear.